# Usage of pipe ( | ) in Linux

Tags: linux

I am a bit confused regarding the usage of pipe `|` in python. I need a in depth explanation of its significance. Users please enlighten me regarding this.

Suppose I issued a command, `ps aux | grep python` then it shows the python processes running on the machine. I do understand it, but I need a analysed and in detail knowledge. Please help me out.

Comment: Maybe do a little [searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command you listed is a shell command, not anything to do with Python specifically.  You are saying:

"run the command `ps aux` and, instead of showing me the result, provide the result as input to `grep python`".  Or, in other words, "pipe the output of the first command into the input of the second command".

`grep` accepts input and displays as output all of the lines of the input that contain the argument following `grep`.  So `grep python` shows all lines in `ps aux` that contain the word python.

Python here is not being invoked in any way -- you're just filtering for that literal string, `python`, in `ps aux`.

Comment: Yes, I too figured out the same as you explained. Now, I am confirmed so thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

First, it's not Python you're talking about when you run `ps aux | grep python`, it's unix, usually within a bash shell. Second, the pipe operator means that you're taking the output of the first function and inputting it into the 2nd function.

In this case, you're taking the result of your process list from `ps aux` and finding anything to do with python from it using `grep python`. The grep command means that you're searching for the string "python" within the process list outputted by ps.

Comment: It's possible to read this description to imply an order of operations wherein all the output from the first process is read ("taken") before the second process receives any input. It might be worth clarifying that this isn't the case -- that both processes are started at the same time, and that writes from the first are directly shoved into the latter as they happen.

Answer (score 0):

`|` works as `and` of the two statement `ps aux` and `grep python`

So when you type `ps aux | grep python` it will return the common results of the two statement.